# Как передать именованный аргумент функции в декоратор?

Tags: python, декоратор

вот код:

```
def deco(func):
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        print('function kwargs with decorator: ', kwargs)
        func(**kwargs)
    return wrapper

@deco
def func(arg=1):
    print('function kwargs: ', arg)

func()
```

Вот вывод:

```
function kwargs with decorator:  {}
function kwargs:  1
```

а вот то, что я хочу чтобы выводило:

```
function kwargs with decorator:  {'arg': 1}
function kwargs:  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Декоратор "не знает", что там за фасадом функции. Поэтому он вам ничего не сообщит об подобных частностях. В нём можно обратиться только лишь к параметрам, которые вы передаёте прямо:

```
def deco(func):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        print('function kwargs with decorator: ', arg, kwargs)
        func(*arg, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@deco
def func(arg=1):
    print('function kwargs: ', arg)

func()
# ('function kwargs with decorator: ', (), {})
# ('function kwargs: ', 1)
func(1)
# ('function kwargs with decorator: ', (1,), {})
# ('function kwargs: ', 1)
func(**{'arg': 1})
# ('function kwargs with decorator: ', (), {'arg': 1})
# ('function kwargs: ', 1)
```

Узнать о состоянии именованных аргументов функции можно внутри декоратора следующим образом:

```
def deco(func):
    def wrapper(*arg, **kwargs):
        print('function kwargs with decorator: ', arg, kwargs)
        print 'pass arg: ', func.__defaults__
        func(*arg, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

func()
# ('function kwargs with decorator: ', (), {})
# pass arg:  (1,)
# ('function kwargs: ', 1)
```